# Javascript function is stopping after a certain line

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a javascript function that crops and centers image to 1000px. To do that, I take the width, subtract 1000, divide by 2, and multiply by -1. I then take this value and assign it to margin-left and margin-right. I have it set to run on page load. For some reason, it is not executing my first line of code. Take a look below. (debug alerts are for debug purposes)

**Javascript**

```
function crop()
{
alert("debug")
width = document.getElementById(slide).width
alert("debug")
width = -1((width - 1000)/2)
alert("debug")
document.getElementById(slide).setAttribute("style","margin-left" + width + "px")
alert("debug")
document.getElementById(slide).setAttribute("style","margin-right" + width + "px")
alert("debug")
}
```

This is the element I am trying to get it to apply all this to.

**Element**

```
<div id="mySlides" style="width:1000px; overflow:hidden;">
<img src="img/1.jpg" onclick="slideshow()" id="slide" />
</div>
```

As you can see, it only displays the first debug alert, and doesn't display anything else after that. Can somebody explain why it is ignoring the rest of the code?

Comment: Did you try checking your console?

Comment: im assuming multiplying by -1 is to convert it from neg to positive, so you can just use the function Math.abs((width - 1000)/2)

Comment: @Fabi: No, it's to turn the value from positive to negative.

Answer (score 2):

`slide` is a reference to a variable named `slide`. You probably want `"slide"` (a string), as your `img` element has `id="slide"`.

You should spend some time getting familiar with your browser's debugging tools (`alert()` is a horrible way of debugging). It would have pointed out...

> ReferenceError: slide is not defined

Comment: that gets it to the second line, then it stops again.

Comment: @Snip3r because you miss a `*` between `-1` and `(`

Comment: thanks. As you can see, I am quite new at this. I can probably solve this with the browser's debugger. I'll be deleting this question.

Comment: @Snip3r at the simplest level it's as basic as replacing your `alert()`'s with `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing delimiters around the string here:

```
width = document.getElementById("slide").width;
```

You are missing the multiplication operator here:

```
width = -1 * ((width - 1000)/2);
```

You are missing the string delimiters, and colons in the style declarations, and also you have to put the styles together otherwise the second one will overwrite the first:

```
document.getElementById("slide").setAttribute("style","margin-left:" + width + "px;margin-right:" + width + "px");
```